# Menu links are not working when clicked

Tags: html, css, hover, hyperlink

Please take a look at a site I am developing at: http://zugoil.com/

The main menu links at the top of the page aren't working, you can see you will hover over them fine with the anchor hand appearing, but when clicking them, they don't do anything. I believe the issue is down to the CSS but I can't figure out where the problem is?

Any help?

Many thanks

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="menu-main" class="nav-menu"></ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#menu-main > li > a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // this prevents the default action
    $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
});
```

The function is preventing the default action of your links.

Comment: Dangit, was about to post that :D

Comment: @Ian, I was a little bit faster/early, may be next time, wish u all the best :-)